# Commutation relationship and measurement results

Tags: error-correction, measurement, stabilizer-code, pauli-gates, stim

There are things I do not understand about the following circuit, and I would appreciate it if you could explain.

```
circuit=stim.Circuit(f'''
    MPP X0*X1*X2*X3
    CX 1 0 2 0 3 0 
    M 0
    DETECTOR rec[-1]
''')
dem = circuit.detector_error_model()
print(repr(dem))
```

This circuit initially prepares a stabilizer state stabilized by $XXXX$ through `MPP X0*X1*X2*X3`. I understand that part, but I do not understand what the subsequent operations imply.

One interpretation is that, by measuring $ZZZZ$ with three CNOTs, since $XXXX$ and $ZZZZ$ commute, the state after the measurement is thought to remain stabilized by $XXXX$. However, another interpretation is that we are actually measuring $ZIII$ at the end of the circuit, which anti-commutes with $XXXX$, so the state after the measurement could be considered to be in a state that is not stabilized by $XXXX$. Which interpretation is correct? In fact, simulations by Stim consistently return trivial measurement results, which suggests the former interpretation is correct. However, I do not understand why it's not appropriate to consider that we're measuring $ZIII$, which anti-commutes with $XXXX$.

Answer (score 0):

The CNOTs also transform the XXXX stabilizer.

```
import stim
xxxx_before = stim.PauliString("XXXX")
zzzz_before = stim.PauliString("ZZZZ")
print('xxxx_before:', xxxx_before)
print('zzzz_before:', zzzz_before)
print('commutes:', xxxx_before.commutes(zzzz_before))

circuit = stim.Circuit(f'''
    CX 1 0 2 0 3 0
''')

xxxx_after = xxxx_before.after(circuit)
zzzz_after = zzzz_before.after(circuit)
print('xxxx_after=:', xxxx_after)
print('zzzz_after=:', zzzz_after)
print('commutes:', xxxx_after.commutes(zzzz_after))
```

```
xxxx_before: +XXXX
zzzz_before: +ZZZZ
commutes: True
xxxx_after=: +_XXX
zzzz_after=: +Z___
commutes: True
```

Comment: I don't understand why the stabilizer transforms in that way due to the CNOT. How can I understand why it becomes `xxxx_after=: +XXX` and `zzzz_after=: +Z__`?

Comment: @david To get P past C in a circuit, introduce the identity C^-1*C before P and then shift focus so that the C you added is the original C instead of the new C. So now you have C followed by (C * P * C^-1) . Moving P past C turned it into (C * P * C^-1). Thus P.after(C) = (C * P * C^-1). Compute this by hand for the given Pauli strings and you will see it works. The stabilizer formalism is built out of understanding conjugating Pauli products by Clifford gates like this.